# Is it grammatical to say: Your understanding is correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it grammatically correct to say: Your understanding is correct to re-assure a concept?

Comment: Please never just ask “Is this correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is grammatically correct and it would re-assure the target that their understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here are [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/understanding)'s (relatively) distinct senses for the noun *understanding*...

> 1: The quality or condition of one who understands; comprehension.
>   2: The faculty by which one understands; intelligence.
>   3: **Individual or specified judgment or outlook; opinion**.
>   4: A compact implicit between two or more people, or the matter implicit in such a compact.
>   5: A reconciliation of differences; a state of agreement: *They finally reached an understanding.*
>   6: A disposition to appreciate or share the feelings and thoughts of others; sympathy.

...where the highlighted entry applies in OP's case *(your understanding = **what** you think)*.

---

This shift in meaning from the generic *ability to understand* in #1 to the *specific thing understood* in #3 is quite common in English, and can be seen with many other words...

> *My **reading** of the situation is that we are under attack by extraterrestrials.
>
>    Your **thinking** is completely off-the-planet.
>
>    My **sense** is that we are living in different worlds.*

...where highlighted words are implicitly "particularised" to refer to the specific concepts following.